# can p4 integrate work between two depots

Tags: perforce

I want to integrate change from one p4 depot to another p4 depot. so something like

p4 integrate //depot1/source/  //depot2/destination

this is currently failing for me. I wanted to know if this is possible in theory? 
Both the depots are running in same server under same p4d daemon

The error I get on p4 submit is -

**Error in change specification.
Can't include file(s) not already opened.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

If you're looking for an explanation as to why it's not working in your case I suggest including the error message in your question (I'd guess it's a very simple usage and/or configuration error)...

Comment: thank you for replying. I have included the error. When both source and destination are in the same depot then things work fine.

Comment: It sounds like you're doing something unusual in your "p4 submit", like adding files to the changelist that you didn't open -- are you submitting normally via the command line or using a script that builds the submit form independently of what the server gives you by default?  Or maybe your permissions are really weird and you have permission to submit the files but not to view them and that's resulting in a weird submit error?  I doubt this has anything to do with the fact that the files are in different depots.

Comment: If you'd like help debugging this I'd suggest posting the exact commands you're running (and their output) on forums.perforce.com; this is more of a tech support thing and less of a stackoverflow type of question.  It's probably something very simple but it's hard to guess what it is without seeing what commands you're running.